# iOS video not playing with MPMoviePlayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'am making video player module for my app.

This is my .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

@interface SpanishViewController : UIViewController
- (IBAction)Video1Button:(id)sender;

@property (nonatomic, strong) MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer;


@end
```

This is code of event executed by button in .m file:

```
- (IBAction)Video1Button:(id)sender {

    NSString *filepath   =   [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"01" ofType:@"mp4"];
    NSURL    *fileURL    =   [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlaybackComplete:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:moviePlayerController];

    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
    moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;

    [moviePlayerController play];
}
```

Video encoded in mp4 in accordance with the standards and runs on iOS.
Result is - [here](http://cl.ly/image/3A3d3z0g1A22)

Video does not start, the button "Done" does not work .. I can not understand what went wrong.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the problem is, 
instead of using global property

`@property (nonatomic, strong) MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer;`

you have re-declared a MPMoviePlayerController in your - (IBAction)Video1Button:(id)sender; method.

Because of that, life of the moviePlayer ends with the end of **Video1Button** method.

correct way,

```
- (IBAction)Video1Button:(id)sender {

    NSString *filepath   =   [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"01" ofType:@"mp4"];
    NSURL    *fileURL    =   [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];
    _moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlaybackComplete:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:self.moviePlayerController];

    [self.view addSubview:_moviePlayerController.view];
    _moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;

    [_moviePlayerController play];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your video1Button method like this.

```
- (IBAction)Video1Button:(id)sender {

    NSString *filepath   =   [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"01" ofType:@"mp4"];
    NSURL    *fileURL    =   [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];
    self.moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlaybackComplete:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:self.moviePlayerController];

    [self.view addSubview:self.moviePlayerController.view];
    self.moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;

    [self.moviePlayerController play];
}
```